# About "having" in SQL

Tags: group-by, sqlite, query

I have the problem:

> Find all the customers that have an order that was handled by employee number 129 and count all the orders they made.

What I tried:

```
select c.id, c.fname, count(*)
from customer c inner join sales_order so 
on c.id = so.cust_id 
group by c.id, c.fname 
having so.sales_rep = 129;
```

But it isn't correct and the answer is:

```
select c.id, c.fname, count(*)
from customer c inner join sales_order so 
where c.id = so.cust_id and c.id in (
select s.cust_id
from sales_order s 
where s.sales_rep = 129)
group by c.id, c.fname;
```

Isn't the keyword `having` in SQL like a condition that runs on each group? Then why won't all the groups that have `so.sales_rep = 129` come up?

These are the outputs: https://pastebin.com/J9LD1L9L

Comment: Why can't you use 'where so.sales_rep=129'  in the first query?

Comment: We want to count all of their orders, including orders that were made by other sales reps from 129. @TomV

Comment: Here's the database.sql file in pastebin: https://pastebin.com/XrfTLbqZ @Vérace

Comment: Your code "sample" is far too big to run on db-fiddle - anyway, the principles are the same - you should be able to run the code I've shown you on your local server? Also, see what I wrote (in edit) about SQLite being modelled on PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

To answer this, I did the following. I used PostgreSQL 9.6 on [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) (a very useful site for putting up code to help ask good questions!). All other servers should act the same way (unless you're using MySQL without [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) when you can get, ahem..., unpredictable results. You should **never** do this!). p.s. SQLite actually [models itself](https://www.pgcon.org/2014/schedule/events/736.en.html) on PostgreSQL, so any results from one are normally applicable to the other!

`CREATE`ed my `TABLE`s:

```
CREATE TABLE customer
(
  id SERIAL,
  fname VARCHAR (20)
);

CREATE TABLE sales_order
(
  order_id SERIAL,
  cust_id INTEGER,  -- put in FK stuff yourself
  sales_rep INTEGER 
);
```

Input data:

```
INSERT INTO customer (fname) VALUES ('cust_1'), ('cust_2'), ('cust_3');
INSERT INTO sales_order (cust_id, sales_rep)
VALUES
(1, 111), (1, 121), (1, 129), (2, 111), (2, 121), (3, 111), (3, 129), (3, 129);
```

Running your original query (see db-fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mZXLzt551uuhcsDvx3ZBXy/1)), gives the error

```
Query Error: error: column "so.sales_rep" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.
```

If you modify your query slightly, as shown below ([db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mZXLzt551uuhcsDvx3ZBXy/2))

```
select c.id, c.fname, count(*)
from customer c inner join sales_order so 
on c.id = so.cust_id 
group by c.id, c.fname, so.sales_rep  -- Note addition of so.sales_rep!
having so.sales_rep = 129;
```

you get the correct answer

```
id  fname   count
3   cust_3  2
1   cust_1  1
```

I personally would find it more helpful to include the sales rep's name (or join it to a sales_rep table to include his/her name ([db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mZXLzt551uuhcsDvx3ZBXy/3)).

The `HAVING` clause is looking for so.sales_rep in its processing, but can't find it in your original - adding it in the `GROUP BY` gives the `HAVING` the information it needs to only produce results for sales_rep no. 129!

Comment: Why does the `so.sales_rep` have to be in the `group by` and why does it make it behave differently? The count is not correct but the names are correct now: https://i.imgur.com/IEWHvYh.png (I added a link to the db in the comments to the question)

Comment: The results are correct using the data I used in db-fiddle. I don't have the time to write out your raw text into SQL statements by hand - this is why it's good to use db-fiddle! `so.sales_rep` **has** to be in the query **because `HAVING` can only act upon fields that are in the `GROUP BY`** - it "doesn't know" about other stuff. It says, "Right, I've got this query above me returning results - now, I need to get those results for which the sales_rep = 129 - but hey, I've no way of knowing this, so I'll throw an error until the programmer gives me the information I need to do my job!"